# Jenkins Declarative Pipeline won't work with Docker Swarm

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-swarm

Running this simple pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'docker-swarm' }
    /* ------------------- */
    stages {
        stage("Build") {
            agent {
                docker {
                  reuseNode true
                  image 'maven:3.5.0-jdk-8'
                }
            }
            steps {
                sh 'mvn -version'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Produces this error:
`Queued: All nodes of label ‘docker-swarm’ are offline`

After ~1 minute the error message changes to:
`Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?`

The strange thing is that when I test the connection in `Manage Jenkins → Cloud` it can connect without a problem:
[image]

Anybody got an idea hot to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

**Update 11/27/2017**:  The screenshot shows an incorrect configuration which does not use the swarm, but instead uses a single manager node.  To use the swarm, I switched to port `3376` and the *Test Connection* output changes to `Version = swarm/1.2.8, API Version = 1.22`.  I noticed my mistake after never seeing builds run on the other nodes in the swarm, and the swarm manager getting overwhelmed.

---

In the original question it is not clear what versions of the various Jenkins plugins are being used, nor how the swarm was configured.

I have successfully used:

- Jenkins 2.73.3
- Docker Plugin 1.0.4
- Standalone (aka Classic) Docker Swarm

At the time I write this, the newer Docker Swarm mode was not supported by the [Docker Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Docker+Plugin). Although a non-swarm docker engine supposedly would work.

Configured like so:
[image: Jenkins Cloud Docker Configuration]

The credentials provide the certificates needed to connect to the swarm.  I do recall it taking me a few tries to get that right.

---

The following pipeline works:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker 'maven:3.5.0-jdk-8'
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'mvn -version'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Giving output:

```
Apache Maven 3.5.0 (ff8f5e7444045639af65f6095c62210b5713f426; 2017-04-03T19:39:06Z)
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_141, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: en, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.4.93-boot2docker", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

The key differences with the pipeline in the original question are:

- Use of a single pipeline scoped `agent` with the image.
- Not using `reuseNode`.
- Not using `label`.

I have not personally tried `reuseNode` or `label`.

Comment: In this scenario - you have multiple docker nodes in your swarm - and any of those nodes may be tasked to perform the Jenkins work?

Comment: @dtmland Yes, exactly. The Docker Plugin allows the swarm to serve as a cloud provider for running jobs in containers.  The larger your swarm, the more containerized jobs you can run in parallel, the work spread across the swarm nodes.  Scale the swarm and Jenkins' job capacity scales with it.  Instead of managing a pool of Jenkins slave servers with various software installed, you manage the Jenkins slave image and agent, leveraging the swarm to run it as the container for jobs.  You can research choices around whether to use a "Docker in Docker" or "Docker outside of Docker" strategy here.